# How to extract a row from a listbox based on the maximum value of one of it's columns in Visual Basic 2010

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a listbox in Visual Basic 2010. So in summary, I'd like to go through each row and for each MaxWeight category, go through the Maxspeed values and print out the row with the highest T_final value, which at the same time maximizes MaxSpeed at that specific Maxweight.

Thus  1) For each Weight category
2) Order T_final in Descending order
3) Select highest T_final value corresponding to highest possible Maxspeed value.

Underneath is the raw data;

```
Group  Max Weight  Max Speed      T_Desc      T_Emerg      T_Final     Time
2   80000       1   404 0   404 840

2   80000       2   0   0   0   420

2   80000       3   0   0   0   280

2   80000       4   0   0   0   210

2   80000       5   0   0   0   168

2   80000       6   0   0   0   140

2   80000       7   0   0   0   120

2   80000       8   0   0   0   105

2   80000       9   0   0   0   93

2   80000       10  0   0   0   84

2   80000       11  0   0   0   76

2   80000       12  0   0   0   70

2   80000       13  0   0   0   65

2   80000       14  0   0   0   60

2   80000       15  0   0   0   56

2   80000       16  0   0   0   52

2   80000       17  0   0   0   49

2   80000       18  0   0   0   47

2   80000       19  0   0   0   44

2   80000       20  0   0   0   42

2   80000       21  0   0   0   40

2   80000       22  0   0   0   38

2   80000       23  0   0   0   37

2   80000       24  0   0   0   35

2   80000       25  0   0   0   34

2   80000       26  0   0   0   32

2   80000       27  0   0   0   31

2   80000       28  0   0   0   30

2   80000       29  0   0   0   29

2   80000       30  0   0   0   28

2   80000       31  0   0   0   27

2   80000       32  0   0   0   26

2   80000       33  0   0   0   25

2   80000       34  0   0   0   25

2   80000       35  0   0   0   24

2   80000       36  0   0   0   23

2   80000       37  0   0   0   23

2   80000       38  0   0   0   22

2   80000       39  0   0   0   22

2   80000       40  0   0   0   21

2   80000       41  0   0   0   20

2   80000       42  0   0   0   20

2   80000       43  0   0   0   20

2   80000       44  0   0   0   19

2   80000       45  0   0   0   19

2   80000       46  0   0   0   18

2   80000       47  0   0   0   18

2   80000       48  0   0   0   18

2   80000       49  0   0   0   17

2   80000       50  0   0   0   17

2   80000       51  0   0   0   16

2   80000       52  0   0   0   16

2   80000       53  0   0   0   16

2   80000       54  0   0   0   16

2   80000       55  0   0   0   15

2   80000       56  0   0   0   15

2   80000       57  0   0   0   15

2   80000       58  0   0   0   14

2   80000       59  0   0   0   14

2   80000       60  0   0   0   14

2   80000       61  0   0   0   14

2   80000       62  0   0   0   14

2   80000       63  0   0   0   13

2   80000       64  0   0   0   13

2   80000       65  0   0   0   13

2   75000       1   361 0   361 840

2   75000       2   0   0   0   420

2   75000       3   0   0   0   280

2   75000       4   0   0   0   210

2   75000       5   0   0   0   168

2   75000       6   0   0   0   140

2   75000       7   0   0   0   120

2   75000       8   0   0   0   105

2   75000       9   0   0   0   93

2   75000       10  0   0   0   84

2   75000       11  0   0   0   76

2   75000       12  0   0   0   70

2   75000       13  0   0   0   65

2   75000       14  0   0   0   60

2   75000       15  0   0   0   56

2   75000       16  0   0   0   52

2   75000       17  0   0   0   49

2   75000       18  0   0   0   47

2   75000       19  0   0   0   44

2   75000       20  0   0   0   42

2   75000       21  0   0   0   40

2   75000       22  0   0   0   38

2   75000       23  0   0   0   37

2   75000       24  0   0   0   35

2   75000       25  0   0   0   34

2   75000       26  0   0   0   32

2   75000       27  0   0   0   31

2   75000       28  0   0   0   30

2   75000       29  0   0   0   29

2   75000       30  0   0   0   28

2   75000       31  0   0   0   27

2   75000       32  0   0   0   26

2   75000       33  0   0   0   25

2   75000       34  0   0   0   25

2   75000       35  0   0   0   24

2   75000       36  0   0   0   23

2   75000       37  0   0   0   23

2   75000       38  0   0   0   22

2   75000       39  0   0   0   22

2   75000       40  0   0   0   21

2   75000       41  0   0   0   20

2   75000       42  0   0   0   20

2   75000       43  0   0   0   20

2   75000       44  0   0   0   19

2   75000       45  0   0   0   19

2   75000       46  0   0   0   18

2   75000       47  0   0   0   18

2   75000       48  0   0   0   18

2   75000       49  0   0   0   17

2   75000       50  0   0   0   17

2   75000       51  0   0   0   16

2   75000       52  0   0   0   16

2   75000       53  0   0   0   16

2   75000       54  0   0   0   16

2   75000       55  0   0   0   15

2   75000       56  0   0   0   15

2   75000       57  0   0   0   15

2   75000       58  0   0   0   14

2   75000       59  0   0   0   14

2   75000       60  0   0   0   14

2   75000       61  0   0   0   14

2   75000       62  0   0   0   14

2   75000       63  0   0   0   13

2   75000       64  0   0   0   13

2   75000       65  0   0   0   13

2   70000       1   317 0   317 840

2   70000       2   0   0   0   420

2   70000       3   0   0   0   280

2   70000       4   0   0   0   210

2   70000       5   0   0   0   168

2   70000       6   0   0   0   140

2   70000       7   0   0   0   120

2   70000       8   0   0   0   105

2   70000       9   0   0   0   93

2   70000       10  0   0   0   84

2   70000       11  0   0   0   76

2   70000       12  0   0   0   70

2   70000       13  0   0   0   65

2   70000       14  0   0   0   60

2   70000       15  0   0   0   56

2   70000       16  0   0   0   52

2   70000       17  0   0   0   49

2   70000       18  0   0   0   47

2   70000       19  0   0   0   44

2   70000       20  0   0   0   42

2   70000       21  0   0   0   40

2   70000       22  0   0   0   38

2   70000       23  0   0   0   37

2   70000       24  0   0   0   35

2   70000       25  0   0   0   34

2   70000       26  0   0   0   32

2   70000       27  0   0   0   31

2   70000       28  0   0   0   30

2   70000       29  0   0   0   29

2   70000       30  0   0   0   28

2   70000       31  0   0   0   27

2   70000       32  0   0   0   26

2   70000       33  0   0   0   25

2   70000       34  0   0   0   25

2   70000       35  0   0   0   24

2   70000       36  0   0   0   23

2   70000       37  0   0   0   23

2   70000       38  0   0   0   22

2   70000       39  0   0   0   22

2   70000       40  0   0   0   21

2   70000       41  0   0   0   20

2   70000       42  0   0   0   20

2   70000       43  0   0   0   20

2   70000       44  0   0   0   19

2   70000       45  0   0   0   19

2   70000       46  0   0   0   18

2   70000       47  0   0   0   18

2   70000       48  0   0   0   18

2   70000       49  0   0   0   17

2   70000       50  0   0   0   17

2   70000       51  0   0   0   16

2   70000       52  0   0   0   16

2   70000       53  0   0   0   16

2   70000       54  0   0   0   16

2   70000       55  0   0   0   15

2   70000       56  0   0   0   15

2   70000       57  0   0   0   15

2   70000       58  0   0   0   14

2   70000       59  0   0   0   14

2   70000       60  0   0   0   14

2   70000       61  0   0   0   14

2   70000       62  0   0   0   14

2   70000       63  0   0   0   13

2   70000       64  0   0   0   13

2   70000       65  0   0   0   13

2   65000       1   273 0   273 840

2   65000       2   0   0   0   420

2   65000       3   0   0   0   280

2   65000       4   0   0   0   210

2   65000       5   0   0   0   168

2   65000       6   0   0   0   140

2   65000       7   0   0   0   120

2   65000       8   0   0   0   105

2   65000       9   0   0   0   93

2   65000       10  0   0   0   84

2   65000       11  0   0   0   76

2   65000       12  0   0   0   70

2   65000       13  0   0   0   65

2   65000       14  0   0   0   60

2   65000       15  0   0   0   56

2   65000       16  0   0   0   52

2   65000       17  0   0   0   49

2   65000       18  0   0   0   47

2   65000       19  0   0   0   44

2   65000       20  0   0   0   42

2   65000       21  0   0   0   40

2   65000       22  0   0   0   38

2   65000       23  0   0   0   37

2   65000       24  0   0   0   35

2   65000       25  0   0   0   34

2   65000       26  0   0   0   32

2   65000       27  0   0   0   31

2   65000       28  0   0   0   30

2   65000       29  0   0   0   29

2   65000       30  0   0   0   28

2   65000       31  0   0   0   27

2   65000       32  0   0   0   26

2   65000       33  0   0   0   25

2   65000       34  0   0   0   25

2   65000       35  0   0   0   24

2   65000       36  0   0   0   23

2   65000       37  0   0   0   23

2   65000       38  0   0   0   22

2   65000       39  0   0   0   22

2   65000       40  0   0   0   21

2   65000       41  0   0   0   20

2   65000       42  0   0   0   20

2   65000       43  0   0   0   20

2   65000       44  0   0   0   19

2   65000       45  0   0   0   19

2   65000       46  0   0   0   18

2   65000       47  0   0   0   18

2   65000       48  0   0   0   18

2   65000       49  0   0   0   17

2   65000       50  0   0   0   17

2   65000       51  0   0   0   16

2   65000       52  0   0   0   16

2   65000       53  0   0   0   16

2   65000       54  0   0   0   16

2   65000       55  0   0   0   15

2   65000       56  0   0   0   15

2   65000       57  0   0   0   15

2   65000       58  0   0   0   14

2   65000       59  0   0   0   14

2   65000       60  0   0   0   14

2   65000       61  0   0   0   14

2   65000       62  0   0   0   14

2   65000       63  0   0   0   13

2   65000       64  0   0   0   13

2   65000       65  0   0   0   13

2   60000       1   230 0   230 840

2   60000       2   0   0   0   420

2   60000       3   0   0   0   280

2   60000       4   0   0   0   210

2   60000       5   0   0   0   168

2   60000       6   0   0   0   140

2   60000       7   0   0   0   120

2   60000       8   0   0   0   105

2   60000       9   0   0   0   93

2   60000       10  0   0   0   84

2   60000       11  0   0   0   76

2   60000       12  0   0   0   70

2   60000       13  0   0   0   65

2   60000       14  0   0   0   60

2   60000       15  0   0   0   56

2   60000       16  0   0   0   52

2   60000       17  0   0   0   49

2   60000       18  0   0   0   47

2   60000       19  0   0   0   44

2   60000       20  0   0   0   42

2   60000       21  0   0   0   40

2   60000       22  0   0   0   38

2   60000       23  0   0   0   37

2   60000       24  0   0   0   35

2   60000       25  0   0   0   34

2   60000       26  0   0   0   32

2   60000       27  0   0   0   31

2   60000       28  0   0   0   30

2   60000       29  0   0   0   29

2   60000       30  0   0   0   28

2   60000       31  0   0   0   27

2   60000       32  0   0   0   26

2   60000       33  0   0   0   25

2   60000       34  0   0   0   25

2   60000       35  0   0   0   24

2   60000       36  0   0   0   23

2   60000       37  0   0   0   23

2   60000       38  0   0   0   22

2   60000       39  0   0   0   22

2   60000       40  0   0   0   21

2   60000       41  0   0   0   20

2   60000       42  0   0   0   20

2   60000       43  0   0   0   20

2   60000       44  0   0   0   19

2   60000       45  0   0   0   19

2   60000       46  0   0   0   18

2   60000       47  0   0   0   18

2   60000       48  0   0   0   18

2   60000       49  0   0   0   17

2   60000       50  0   0   0   17

2   60000       51  0   0   0   16

2   60000       52  0   0   0   16

2   60000       53  0   0   0   16

2   60000       54  0   0   0   16

2   60000       55  0   0   0   15

2   60000       56  0   0   0   15

2   60000       57  0   0   0   15

2   60000       58  0   0   0   14

2   60000       59  0   0   0   14

2   60000       60  0   0   0   14

2   60000       61  0   0   0   14

2   60000       62  0   0   0   14

2   60000       63  0   0   0   13

2   60000       64  0   0   0   13

2   60000       65  0   0   0   13

2   55000       1   186 0   186 840

2   55000       2   0   0   0   420

2   55000       3   0   0   0   280

2   55000       4   0   0   0   210

2   55000       5   0   0   0   168

2   55000       6   0   0   0   140

2   55000       7   0   0   0   120

2   55000       8   0   0   0   105

2   55000       9   0   0   0   93

2   55000       10  0   0   0   84

2   55000       11  0   0   0   76

2   55000       12  0   0   0   70

2   55000       13  0   0   0   65

2   55000       14  0   0   0   60

2   55000       15  0   0   0   56

2   55000       16  0   0   0   52

2   55000       17  0   0   0   49

2   55000       18  0   0   0   47

2   55000       19  0   0   0   44

2   55000       20  0   0   0   42

2   55000       21  0   0   0   40

2   55000       22  0   0   0   38

2   55000       23  0   0   0   37

2   55000       24  0   0   0   35

2   55000       25  0   0   0   34

2   55000       26  0   0   0   32

2   55000       27  0   0   0   31

2   55000       28  0   0   0   30

2   55000       29  0   0   0   29

2   55000       30  0   0   0   28

2   55000       31  0   0   0   27

2   55000       32  0   0   0   26

2   55000       33  0   0   0   25

2   55000       34  0   0   0   25

2   55000       35  0   0   0   24

2   55000       36  0   0   0   23

2   55000       37  0   0   0   23

2   55000       38  0   0   0   22

2   55000       39  0   0   0   22

2   55000       40  0   0   0   21

2   55000       41  0   0   0   20

2   55000       42  0   0   0   20

2   55000       43  0   0   0   20

2   55000       44  0   0   0   19

2   55000       45  0   0   0   19

2   55000       46  0   0   0   18

2   55000       47  0   0   0   18

2   55000       48  0   0   0   18

2   55000       49  0   0   0   17

2   55000       50  0   0   0   17

2   55000       51  0   0   0   16

2   55000       52  0   0   0   16

2   55000       53  0   0   0   16

2   55000       54  0   0   0   16

2   55000       55  0   0   0   15

2   55000       56  0   0   0   15

2   55000       57  0   0   0   15

2   55000       58  0   0   0   14

2   55000       59  0   0   0   14

2   55000       60  0   0   0   14

2   55000       61  0   0   0   14

2   55000       62  0   0   0   14

2   55000       63  0   0   0   13

2   55000       64  0   0   0   13

2   55000       65  0   0   0   13

2   50000       1   142 0   142 840

2   50000       2   0   0   0   420

2   50000       3   0   0   0   280

2   50000       4   0   0   0   210

2   50000       5   0   0   0   168

2   50000       6   0   0   0   140

2   50000       7   0   0   0   120

2   50000       8   0   0   0   105

2   50000       9   0   0   0   93

2   50000       10  0   0   0   84

2   50000       11  0   0   0   76

2   50000       12  0   0   0   70

2   50000       13  0   0   0   65

2   50000       14  0   0   0   60

2   50000       15  0   0   0   56

2   50000       16  0   0   0   52

2   50000       17  0   0   0   49

2   50000       18  0   0   0   47

2   50000       19  0   0   0   44

2   50000       20  0   0   0   42

2   50000       21  0   0   0   40

2   50000       22  0   0   0   38

2   50000       23  0   0   0   37

2   50000       24  0   0   0   35

2   50000       25  0   0   0   34

2   50000       26  0   0   0   32

2   50000       27  0   0   0   31

2   50000       28  0   0   0   30

2   50000       29  0   0   0   29

2   50000       30  0   0   0   28

2   50000       31  0   0   0   27

2   50000       32  0   0   0   26

2   50000       33  0   0   0   25

2   50000       34  0   0   0   25

2   50000       35  0   0   0   24

2   50000       36  0   0   0   23

2   50000       37  0   0   0   23

2   50000       38  0   0   0   22

2   50000       39  0   0   0   22

2   50000       40  0   0   0   21

2   50000       41  0   0   0   20

2   50000       42  0   0   0   20

2   50000       43  0   0   0   20

2   50000       44  0   0   0   19

2   50000       45  0   0   0   19

2   50000       46  0   0   0   18

2   50000       47  0   0   0   18

2   50000       48  0   0   0   18

2   50000       49  0   0   0   17

2   50000       50  0   0   0   17

2   50000       51  0   0   0   16

2   50000       52  0   0   0   16

2   50000       53  0   0   0   16

2   50000       54  0   0   0   16

2   50000       55  0   0   0   15

2   50000       56  0   0   0   15

2   50000       57  0   0   0   15

2   50000       58  0   0   0   14

2   50000       59  0   0   0   14

2   50000       60  0   0   0   14

2   50000       61  0   0   0   14

2   50000       62  0   0   0   14

2   50000       63  0   0   0   13

2   50000       64  0   0   0   13

2   50000       65  0   0   0   13

2   45000       1   99  0   99  840

2   45000       2   466 0   466 420

2   45000       3   0   0   0   280

2   45000       4   0   0   0   210

2   45000       5   0   0   0   168

2   45000       6   0   0   0   140

2   45000       7   0   0   0   120

2   45000       8   0   0   0   105

2   45000       9   0   0   0   93

2   45000       10  0   0   0   84

2   45000       11  0   0   0   76

2   45000       12  0   0   0   70

2   45000       13  0   0   0   65

2   45000       14  0   0   0   60

2   45000       15  0   0   0   56

2   45000       16  0   0   0   52

2   45000       17  0   0   0   49

2   45000       18  0   0   0   47

2   45000       19  0   0   0   44

2   45000       20  0   0   0   42

2   45000       21  0   0   0   40

2   45000       22  0   0   0   38

2   45000       23  0   0   0   37

2   45000       24  0   0   0   35

2   45000       25  0   0   0   34

2   45000       26  0   0   0   32

2   45000       27  0   0   0   31

2   45000       28  0   0   0   30

2   45000       29  0   0   0   29

2   45000       30  0   0   0   28

2   45000       31  0   0   0   27

2   45000       32  0   0   0   26

2   45000       33  0   0   0   25

2   45000       34  0   0   0   25

2   45000       35  0   0   0   24

2   45000       36  0   0   0   23

2   45000       37  0   0   0   23

2   45000       38  0   0   0   22

2   45000       39  0   0   0   22

2   45000       40  0   0   0   21

2   45000       41  0   0   0   20

2   45000       42  0   0   0   20

2   45000       43  0   0   0   20

2   45000       44  0   0   0   19

2   45000       45  0   0   0   19

2   45000       46  0   0   0   18

2   45000       47  0   0   0   18

2   45000       48  0   0   0   18

2   45000       49  0   0   0   17

2   45000       50  0   0   0   17

2   45000       51  0   0   0   16

2   45000       52  0   0   0   16

2   45000       53  0   0   0   16

2   45000       54  0   0   0   16

2   45000       55  0   0   0   15

2   45000       56  0   0   0   15

2   45000       57  0   0   0   15

2   45000       58  0   0   0   14

2   45000       59  0   0   0   14

2   45000       60  0   0   0   14

2   45000       61  0   0   0   14

2   45000       62  0   0   0   14

2   45000       63  0   0   0   13

2   45000       64  0   0   0   13

2   45000       65  0   0   0   13

2   40000       1   55  0   55  840

2   40000       2   382 0   382 420

2   40000       3   0   0   0   280

2   40000       4   0   0   0   210

2   40000       5   0   0   0   168

2   40000       6   0   0   0   140

2   40000       7   0   0   0   120

2   40000       8   0   0   0   105

2   40000       9   0   0   0   93

2   40000       10  0   0   0   84

2   40000       11  0   0   0   76

2   40000       12  0   0   0   70

2   40000       13  0   0   0   65

2   40000       14  0   0   0   60

2   40000       15  0   0   0   56

2   40000       16  0   0   0   52

2   40000       17  0   0   0   49

2   40000       18  0   0   0   47

2   40000       19  0   0   0   44

2   40000       20  0   0   0   42

2   40000       21  0   0   0   40

2   40000       22  0   0   0   38

2   40000       23  0   0   0   37

2   40000       24  0   0   0   35

2   40000       25  0   0   0   34

2   40000       26  0   0   0   32

2   40000       27  0   0   0   31

2   40000       28  0   0   0   30

2   40000       29  0   0   0   29

2   40000       30  0   0   0   28

2   40000       31  0   0   0   27

2   40000       32  0   0   0   26

2   40000       33  0   0   0   25

2   40000       34  0   0   0   25

2   40000       35  0   0   0   24

2   40000       36  0   0   0   23

2   40000       37  0   0   0   23

2   40000       38  0   0   0   22

2   40000       39  0   0   0   22

2   40000       40  0   0   0   21

2   40000       41  0   0   0   20

2   40000       42  0   0   0   20

2   40000       43  0   0   0   20

2   40000       44  0   0   0   19

2   40000       45  0   0   0   19

2   40000       46  0   0   0   18

2   40000       47  0   0   0   18

2   40000       48  0   0   0   18

2   40000       49  0   0   0   17

2   40000       50  0   0   0   17

2   40000       51  0   0   0   16

2   40000       52  0   0   0   16

2   40000       53  0   0   0   16

2   40000       54  0   0   0   16

2   40000       55  0   0   0   15

2   40000       56  0   0   0   15

2   40000       57  0   0   0   15

2   40000       58  0   0   0   14

2   40000       59  0   0   0   14

2   40000       60  0   0   0   14

2   40000       61  0   0   0   14

2   40000       62  0   0   0   14

2   40000       63  0   0   0   13

2   40000       64  0   0   0   13

2   40000       65  0   0   0   13

2   35000       1   11  0   11  840

2   35000       2   299 0   299 420

2   35000       3   0   0   0   280

2   35000       4   0   0   0   210

2   35000       5   0   0   0   168

2   35000       6   0   0   0   140

2   35000       7   0   0   0   120

2   35000       8   0   0   0   105

2   35000       9   0   0   0   93

2   35000       10  0   0   0   84

2   35000       11  0   0   0   76

2   35000       12  0   0   0   70

2   35000       13  0   0   0   65

2   35000       14  0   0   0   60

2   35000       15  0   0   0   56

2   35000       16  0   0   0   52

2   35000       17  0   0   0   49

2   35000       18  0   0   0   47

2   35000       19  0   0   0   44

2   35000       20  0   0   0   42

2   35000       21  0   0   0   40

2   35000       22  0   0   0   38

2   35000       23  0   0   0   37

2   35000       24  0   0   0   35

2   35000       25  0   0   0   34

2   35000       26  0   0   0   32

2   35000       27  0   0   0   31

2   35000       28  0   0   0   30

2   35000       29  0   0   0   29

2   35000       30  0   0   0   28

2   35000       31  0   0   0   27

2   35000       32  0   0   0   26

2   35000       33  0   0   0   25

2   35000       34  0   0   0   25

2   35000       35  0   0   0   24

2   35000       36  0   0   0   23

2   35000       37  0   0   0   23

2   35000       38  0   0   0   22

2   35000       39  0   0   0   22

2   35000       40  0   0   0   21

2   35000       41  0   0   0   20

2   35000       42  0   0   0   20

2   35000       43  0   0   0   20

2   35000       44  0   0   0   19

2   35000       45  0   0   0   19

2   35000       46  0   0   0   18

2   35000       47  0   0   0   18

2   35000       48  0   0   0   18

2   35000       49  0   0   0   17

2   35000       50  0   0   0   17

2   35000       51  0   0   0   16

2   35000       52  0   0   0   16

2   35000       53  0   0   0   16

2   35000       54  0   0   0   16

2   35000       55  0   0   0   15

2   35000       56  0   0   0   15

2   35000       57  0   0   0   15

2   35000       58  0   0   0   14

2   35000       59  0   0   0   14

2   35000       60  0   0   0   14

2   35000       61  0   0   0   14

2   35000       62  0   0   0   14

2   35000       63  0   0   0   13

2   35000       64  0   0   0   13

2   35000       65  0   0   0   13

2   30000       1   -32 0   -32 840

2   30000       2   216 0   216 420

2   30000       3   440 0   440 280

2   30000       4   0   0   0   210

2   30000       5   0   0   0   168

2   30000       6   0   0   0   140

2   30000       7   0   0   0   120

2   30000       8   0   0   0   105

2   30000       9   0   0   0   93

2   30000       10  0   0   0   84

2   30000       11  0   0   0   76

2   30000       12  0   0   0   70

2   30000       13  0   0   0   65

2   30000       14  0   0   0   60

2   30000       15  0   0   0   56

2   30000       16  0   0   0   52

2   30000       17  0   0   0   49

2   30000       18  0   0   0   47

2   30000       19  0   0   0   44

2   30000       20  0   0   0   42

2   30000       21  0   0   0   40

2   30000       22  0   0   0   38

2   30000       23  0   0   0   37

2   30000       24  0   0   0   35

2   30000       25  0   0   0   34

2   30000       26  0   0   0   32

2   30000       27  0   0   0   31

2   30000       28  0   0   0   30

2   30000       29  0   0   0   29

2   30000       30  0   0   0   28

2   30000       31  0   0   0   27

2   30000       32  0   0   0   26

2   30000       33  0   0   0   25

2   30000       34  0   0   0   25

2   30000       35  0   0   0   24

2   30000       36  0   0   0   23

2   30000       37  0   0   0   23

2   30000       38  0   0   0   22

2   30000       39  0   0   0   22

2   30000       40  0   0   0   21

2   30000       41  0   0   0   20

2   30000       42  0   0   0   20

2   30000       43  0   0   0   20

2   30000       44  0   0   0   19

2   30000       45  0   0   0   19

2   30000       46  0   0   0   18

2   30000       47  0   0   0   18

2   30000       48  0   0   0   18

2   30000       49  0   0   0   17

2   30000       50  0   0   0   17

2   30000       51  0   0   0   16

2   30000       52  0   0   0   16

2   30000       53  0   0   0   16

2   30000       54  0   0   0   16

2   30000       55  0   0   0   15

2   30000       56  0   0   0   15

2   30000       57  0   0   0   15

2   30000       58  0   0   0   14

2   30000       59  0   0   0   14

2   30000       60  0   0   0   14

2   30000       61  0   0   0   14

2   30000       62  0   0   0   14

2   30000       63  0   0   0   13

2   30000       64  0   0   0   13

2   30000       65  0   0   0   13

2   25000       1   -76 0   -76 840

2   25000       2   132 0   133 420

2   25000       3   321 0   321 280

2   25000       4   492 0   492 210

2   25000       5   0   0   0   168

2   25000       6   0   0   0   140

2   25000       7   0   0   0   120

2   25000       8   0   0   0   105

2   25000       9   0   0   0   93

2   25000       10  0   0   0   84

2   25000       11  0   0   0   76

2   25000       12  0   0   0   70

2   25000       13  0   0   0   65

2   25000       14  0   0   0   60

2   25000       15  0   0   0   56

2   25000       16  0   0   0   52

2   25000       17  0   0   0   49

2   25000       18  0   0   0   47

2   25000       19  0   0   0   44

2   25000       20  0   0   0   42

2   25000       21  0   0   0   40

2   25000       22  0   0   0   38

2   25000       23  0   0   0   37

2   25000       24  0   0   0   35

2   25000       25  0   0   0   34

2   25000       26  0   0   0   32

2   25000       27  0   0   0   31

2   25000       28  0   0   0   30

2   25000       29  0   0   0   29

2   25000       30  0   0   0   28

2   25000       31  0   0   0   27

2   25000       32  0   0   0   26

2   25000       33  0   0   0   25

2   25000       34  0   0   0   25

2   25000       35  0   0   0   24

2   25000       36  0   0   0   23

2   25000       37  0   0   0   23

2   25000       38  0   0   0   22

2   25000       39  0   0   0   22

2   25000       40  0   0   0   21

2   25000       41  0   0   0   20

2   25000       42  0   0   0   20

2   25000       43  0   0   0   20

2   25000       44  0   0   0   19

2   25000       45  0   0   0   19

2   25000       46  0   0   0   18

2   25000       47  0   0   0   18

2   25000       48  0   0   0   18

2   25000       49  0   0   0   17

2   25000       50  0   0   0   17

2   25000       51  0   0   0   16

2   25000       52  0   0   0   16

2   25000       53  0   0   0   16

2   25000       54  0   0   0   16

2   25000       55  0   0   0   15

2   25000       56  0   0   0   15

2   25000       57  0   0   0   15

2   25000       58  0   0   0   14

2   25000       59  0   0   0   14

2   25000       60  0   0   0   14

2   25000       61  0   0   0   14

2   25000       62  0   0   0   14

2   25000       63  0   0   0   13

2   25000       64  0   0   0   13

2   25000       65  0   0   0   13

2   20000       1   -119    0   -119    840

2   20000       2   49  0   49  420

2   20000       3   202 0   202 280

2   20000       4   340 0   340 210

2   20000       5   467 0   467 168

2   20000       6   0   0   0   140

2   20000       7   0   0   0   120

2   20000       8   0   0   0   105

2   20000       9   0   0   0   93

2   20000       10  0   0   0   84

2   20000       11  0   0   0   76

2   20000       12  0   0   0   70

2   20000       13  0   0   0   65

2   20000       14  0   0   0   60

2   20000       15  0   0   0   56

2   20000       16  0   0   0   52

2   20000       17  0   0   0   49

2   20000       18  0   0   0   47

2   20000       19  0   0   0   44

2   20000       20  0   0   0   42

2   20000       21  0   0   0   40

2   20000       22  0   0   0   38

2   20000       23  0   0   0   37

2   20000       24  0   0   0   35

2   20000       25  0   0   0   34

2   20000       26  0   0   0   32

2   20000       27  0   0   0   31

2   20000       28  0   0   0   30

2   20000       29  0   0   0   29

2   20000       30  0   0   0   28

2   20000       31  0   0   0   27

2   20000       32  0   0   0   26

2   20000       33  0   0   0   25

2   20000       34  0   0   0   25

2   20000       35  0   0   0   24

2   20000       36  0   0   0   23

2   20000       37  0   0   0   23

2   20000       38  0   0   0   22

2   20000       39  0   0   0   22

2   20000       40  0   0   0   21

2   20000       41  0   0   0   20

2   20000       42  0   0   0   20

2   20000       43  0   0   0   20

2   20000       44  0   0   0   19

2   20000       45  0   0   0   19

2   20000       46  0   0   0   18

2   20000       47  0   0   0   18

2   20000       48  0   0   0   18

2   20000       49  0   0   0   17

2   20000       50  0   0   0   17

2   20000       51  0   0   0   16

2   20000       52  0   0   0   16

2   20000       53  0   0   0   16

2   20000       54  0   0   0   16

2   20000       55  0   0   0   15

2   20000       56  0   0   0   15

2   20000       57  0   0   0   15

2   20000       58  0   0   0   14

2   20000       59  0   0   0   14

2   20000       60  0   0   0   14

2   20000       61  0   0   0   14

2   20000       62  0   0   0   14

2   20000       63  0   0   0   13

2   20000       64  0   0   0   13

2   20000       65  0   0   0   13

2   15000       1   -163    0   -163    840

2   15000       2   -34 0   -34 420

2   15000       3   83  0   83  280

2   15000       4   189 0   189 210

2   15000       5   286 0   286 168

2   15000       6   375 0   375 140

2   15000       7   456 0   456 120

2   15000       8   0   0   0   105

2   15000       9   0   0   0   93

2   15000       10  0   0   0   84

2   15000       11  0   0   0   76

2   15000       12  0   0   0   70

2   15000       13  0   0   0   65

2   15000       14  0   0   0   60

2   15000       15  0   0   0   56

2   15000       16  0   0   0   52

2   15000       17  0   0   0   49

2   15000       18  0   0   0   47

2   15000       19  0   0   0   44

2   15000       20  0   0   0   42

2   15000       21  0   0   0   40

2   15000       22  0   0   0   38

2   15000       23  0   0   0   37

2   15000       24  0   0   0   35

2   15000       25  0   0   0   34

2   15000       26  0   0   0   32

2   15000       27  0   0   0   31

2   15000       28  0   0   0   30

2   15000       29  0   0   0   29

2   15000       30  0   0   0   28

2   15000       31  0   0   0   27

2   15000       32  0   0   0   26

2   15000       33  0   0   0   25

2   15000       34  0   0   0   25

2   15000       35  0   0   0   24

2   15000       36  0   0   0   23

2   15000       37  0   0   0   23

2   15000       38  0   0   0   22

2   15000       39  0   0   0   22

2   15000       40  0   0   0   21

2   15000       41  0   0   0   20

2   15000       42  0   0   0   20

2   15000       43  0   0   0   20

2   15000       44  0   0   0   19

2   15000       45  0   0   0   19

2   15000       46  0   0   0   18

2   15000       47  0   0   0   18

2   15000       48  0   0   0   18

2   15000       49  0   0   0   17

2   15000       50  0   0   0   17

2   15000       51  0   0   0   16

2   15000       52  0   0   0   16

2   15000       53  0   0   0   16

2   15000       54  0   0   0   16

2   15000       55  0   0   0   15

2   15000       56  0   0   0   15

2   15000       57  0   0   0   15

2   15000       58  0   0   0   14

2   15000       59  0   0   0   14

2   15000       60  0   0   0   14

2   15000       61  0   0   0   14

2   15000       62  0   0   0   14

2   15000       63  0   0   0   13

2   15000       64  0   0   0   13

2   15000       65  0   0   0   13

2   10000       1   -207    0   -207    840

2   10000       2   -117    0   -117    420

2   10000       3   -37 0   -37 280

2   10000       4   37  0   37  210

2   10000       5   105 0   105 168

2   10000       6   167 0   167 140

2   10000       7   224 0   224 120

2   10000       8   276 0   276 105

2   10000       9   324 0   324 93

2   10000       10  367 0   367 84

2   10000       11  406 0   407 76

2   10000       12  442 0   442 70

2   10000       13  474 1   475 65

2   10000       14  0   0   0   60

2   10000       15  0   0   0   56

2   10000       16  0   0   0   52

2   10000       17  0   0   0   49

2   10000       18  0   0   0   47

2   10000       19  0   0   0   44

2   10000       20  0   0   0   42

2   10000       21  0   0   0   40

2   10000       22  0   0   0   38

2   10000       23  0   0   0   37

2   10000       24  0   0   0   35

2   10000       25  0   0   0   34

2   10000       26  0   0   0   32

2   10000       27  0   0   0   31

2   10000       28  0   0   0   30

2   10000       29  0   0   0   29

2   10000       30  0   0   0   28

2   10000       31  0   0   0   27

2   10000       32  0   0   0   26

2   10000       33  0   0   0   25

2   10000       34  0   0   0   25

2   10000       35  0   0   0   24

2   10000       36  0   0   0   23

2   10000       37  0   0   0   23

2   10000       38  0   0   0   22

2   10000       39  0   0   0   22

2   10000       40  0   0   0   21

2   10000       41  0   0   0   20

2   10000       42  0   0   0   20

2   10000       43  0   0   0   20

2   10000       44  0   0   0   19

2   10000       45  0   0   0   19

2   10000       46  0   0   0   18

2   10000       47  0   0   0   18

2   10000       48  0   0   0   18

2   10000       49  0   0   0   17

2   10000       50  0   0   0   17

2   10000       51  0   0   0   16

2   10000       52  0   0   0   16

2   10000       53  0   0   0   16

2   10000       54  0   0   0   16

2   10000       55  0   0   0   15

2   10000       56  0   0   0   15

2   10000       57  0   0   0   15

2   10000       58  0   0   0   14

2   10000       59  0   0   0   14

2   10000       60  0   0   0   14

2   10000       61  0   0   0   14

2   10000       62  0   0   0   14

2   10000       63  0   0   0   13

2   10000       64  0   0   0   13

2   10000       65  0   0   0   13

2   5000        1   -250    0   -250    840

2   5000        2   -201    0   -201    420

2   5000        3   -156    0   -156    280

2   5000        4   -114    0   -114    210

2   5000        5   -76 0   -76 168

2   5000        6   -41 0   -41 140

2   5000        7   -8  0   -8  120

2   5000        8   23  0   23  105

2   5000        9   51  0   51  93

2   5000        10  77  0   77  84

2   5000        11  101 0   101 76

2   5000        12  123 0   123 70

2   5000        13  143 0   143 65

2   5000        14  161 0   161 60

2   5000        15  178 0   178 56

2   5000        16  193 0   194 52

2   5000        17  208 0   208 49

2   5000        18  221 1   221 47

2   5000        19  232 1   233 44

2   5000        20  243 1   244 42

2   5000        21  253 1   254 40

2   5000        22  263 1   263 38

2   5000        23  271 1   272 37

2   5000        24  279 1   280 35

2   5000        25  286 1   287 34

2   5000        26  293 1   294 32

2   5000        27  299 1   300 31

2   5000        28  305 1   306 30

2   5000        29  310 1   311 29

2   5000        30  315 1   316 28

2   5000        31  319 1   320 27

2   5000        32  323 2   324 26

2   5000        33  326 2   328 25

2   5000        34  330 2   332 25

2   5000        35  333 2   335 24

2   5000        36  335 2   338 23

2   5000        37  338 2   340 23

2   5000        38  340 2   342 22

2   5000        39  342 2   344 22

2   5000        40  344 2   346 21

2   5000        41  345 3   348 20

2   5000        42  347 3   349 20

2   5000        43  348 3   351 20

2   5000        44  349 3   352 19

2   5000        45  349 3   353 19

2   5000        46  350 3   353 18

2   5000        47  350 3   354 18

2   5000        48  351 4   354 18

2   5000        49  351 4   355 17

2   5000        50  351 4   355 17

2   5000        51  351 4   355 16

2   5000        52  350 4   355 16

2   5000        53  350 4   354 16

2   5000        54  349 5   354 16

2   5000        55  349 5   354 15

2   5000        56  348 5   353 15

2   5000        57  347 5   352 15

2   5000        58  346 5   351 14

2   5000        59  345 5   351 14

2   5000        60  344 6   350 14

2   5000        61  343 6   348 14

2   5000        62  341 6   347 14

2   5000        63  340 6   346 13

2   5000        64  338 6   345 13

2   5000        65  337 7   343 13

2   0       1   -294    0   -294    840

2   0       2   -284    0   -284    420

2   0       3   -275    0   -275    280

2   0       4   -266    0   -266    210

2   0       5   -257    0   -257    168

2   0       6   -249    0   -249    140

2   0       7   -240    0   -240    120

2   0       8   -231    0   -231    105

2   0       9   -222    0   -222    93

2   0       10  -213    0   -213    84

2   0       11  -205    0   -205    76

2   0       12  -197    0   -197    70

2   0       13  -189    0   -189    65

2   0       14  -182    0   -182    60

2   0       15  -175    0   -175    56

2   0       16  -168    0   -168    52

2   0       17  -162    0   -162    49

2   0       18  -157    0   -157    47

2   0       19  -152    0   -152    44

2   0       20  -147    0   -147    42

2   0       21  -142    0   -142    40

2   0       22  -138    0   -138    38

2   0       23  -134    0   -134    37

2   0       24  -131    0   -131    35

2   0       25  -127    0   -127    34

2   0       26  -124    0   -124    32

2   0       27  -121    0   -121    31

2   0       28  -119    0   -119    30

2   0       29  -116    0   -116    29

2   0       30  -114    0   -114    28

2   0       31  -112    0   -112    27

2   0       32  -111    0   -111    26

2   0       33  -109    0   -109    25

2   0       34  -108    0   -108    25

2   0       35  -107    0   -107    24

2   0       36  -106    0   -106    23

2   0       37  -105    0   -105    23

2   0       38  -104    0   -104    22

2   0       39  -103    0   -103    22

2   0       40  -103    0   -103    21

2   0       41  -103    0   -103    20

2   0       42  -102    0   -102    20

2   0       43  -102    0   -102    20

2   0       44  -102    0   -102    19

2   0       45  -103    0   -103    19

2   0       46  -103    0   -103    18

2   0       47  -103    0   -103    18

2   0       48  -104    0   -104    18

2   0       49  -104    0   -104    17

2   0       50  -105    0   -105    17

2   0       51  -106    0   -106    16

2   0       52  -107    0   -107    16

2   0       53  -108    0   -108    16

2   0       54  -109    0   -109    16

2   0       55  -110    0   -110    15

2   0       56  -111    0   -111    15

2   0       57  -113    0   -113    15

2   0       58  -114    0   -114    14

2   0       59  -116    0   -116    14

2   0       60  -117    0   -117    14

2   0       61  -119    0   -119    14

2   0       62  -121    0   -121    14

2   0       63  -123    0   -123    13

2   0       64  -125    0   -125    13

2   0       65  -126    0   -126    13
```

Below is the output I'm seeking. Note especially from MaxWeight of 15,000 to 0.

```
 {'Max_Weight'}    {'Max_Speed'}    {'T_Desc'}    {'T_Emerg'}    {'T_Final'}    {'Time'}
    {[     80000]}    {[        1]}    {[   404]}    {[      0]}    {[    404]}    {[ 840]}
    {[     75000]}    {[        1]}    {[   361]}    {[      0]}    {[    361]}    {[ 840]}
    {[     70000]}    {[        1]}    {[   317]}    {[      0]}    {[    317]}    {[ 840]}
    {[     65000]}    {[        1]}    {[   273]}    {[      0]}    {[    273]}    {[ 840]}
    {[     60000]}    {[        1]}    {[   230]}    {[      0]}    {[    230]}    {[ 840]}
    {[     55000]}    {[        1]}    {[   186]}    {[      0]}    {[    186]}    {[ 840]}
    {[     50000]}    {[        1]}    {[   142]}    {[      0]}    {[    142]}    {[ 840]}
    {[     45000]}    {[        2]}    {[   466]}    {[      0]}    {[    466]}    {[ 420]}
    {[     40000]}    {[        2]}    {[   382]}    {[      0]}    {[    382]}    {[ 420]}
    {[     35000]}    {[        2]}    {[   299]}    {[      0]}    {[    299]}    {[ 420]}
    {[     30000]}    {[        3]}    {[   440]}    {[      0]}    {[    440]}    {[ 280]}
    {[     25000]}    {[        4]}    {[   492]}    {[      0]}    {[    492]}    {[ 210]}
    {[     20000]}    {[        5]}    {[   467]}    {[      0]}    {[    467]}    {[ 168]}
    {[     15000]}    {[        7]}    {[   456]}    {[      0]}    {[    456]}    {[ 120]}
    {[     10000]}    {[       13]}    {[   474]}    {[      1]}    {[    475]}    {[  65]}
    {[      5000]}    {[       65]}    {[   337]}    {[      7]}    {[    343]}    {[  13]}
```

Comment: Had to remove your links. They were pushing malware. Please edit the question to paste a **short excerpt** of the text directly into the question (no more than 10 lines or so), and again to include a sample of the desired result _directly in the question_.

Comment: What kind of OBJECT is in your ListBox?  Is it a String?...a custom object?...something else?  Is your ListBox DATABOUND? If so, DataBound to what?  You might be able to get your answer using LINQ without iterating row by row.  Without details, you're not going to get a good answer...

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn , please take a second look at the modified question.

Comment: Better, but screen shots of your data are still very bad. Treat the text as code or use `<pre>` tags to get the data to show in the question.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn, hope its better now.

Comment: Is the data in your ListBox ALWAYS already sorted by "Max Weight"?  Are the values separated by ONLY spaces, or are there tabs mixed in there as well?

Comment: @Idle_Mind, yes the data in the listbox is always sorted by Max Weight. The values are separated by tabs. Weight Values are separated from Maximum Speed by Two Tabs. Every other value is separated from the next by a single tab.

Comment: Perfect! This is what we need.

Comment: A few more questions. Do you actually want to **Select** the row in the listbox, or just print it out? And what does "print it out" mean in your context? Actually create a print job with a physical printer? Write to Console? Copy to another Listbox?

Comment: Great questions. So before, my code was trying to just remove the irrelevant rows to produce the second result. Alternatively, if you can find the row that maximizes T_desc for every unique Max_Weight, then you can remove all the others from the same list box, leaving only the relevant (selected) items. @JoelCoehoorn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on all your responses, try something like the below out.  It parses the string data into DataValue instances (code assumes spaces and/or tabs between values), then uses a LINQ query to get the largest "T_Desc" for each "MaxWeight" group, and repopulates the ListBox with the new data.  The code assumes that the first row in the ListBox was a header row, and leaves that intact:

[image]

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim header As String = lstOutput.Items(0)

        Dim data As New List(Of DataValue)
        ' Skip the header row by starting at 1:
        For i As Integer = 1 To lstOutput.Items.Count - 1
            data.Add(New DataValue(lstOutput.Items(i)))
        Next

        Dim results = From dv In data
                      Order By dv.MaxWeight Descending, dv.T_Desc Descending
                      Group dv By dv.MaxWeight Into g = Group
                      Select g.First

        lstOutput.Items.Clear()
        lstOutput.Items.Add(header)
        For Each row In results
            lstOutput.Items.Add(row.ToString)
        Next
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class DataValue

    Public Sub New(ByVal strInput As String)
        Dim values() As String = strInput.Split({" ", vbTab}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        If values.Length >= 6 Then
            Try
                MaxWeight = Integer.Parse(values(0))
                MaxSpeed = Integer.Parse(values(1))
                Time = Integer.Parse(values(2))
                T_Emerg = Integer.Parse(values(3))
                T_Final = Integer.Parse(values(4))
                T_Desc = Integer.Parse(values(5))
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid Input: Value failed to convert to Integer.")
            End Try
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid Input: Not enough values.")
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return MaxWeight & vbTab & MaxSpeed & vbTab & Time & vbTab & T_Emerg & vbTab & T_Final & vbTab & T_Desc
    End Function

    Public MaxWeight As Integer
    Public MaxSpeed As Integer
    Public Time As Integer
    Public T_Emerg As Integer
    Public T_Final As Integer
    Public T_Desc As Integer

End Class
```

Not sure where your data is coming from...you could create DataValue instances directly from the data, and then add those instances to the ListBox instead of converting back and forth between strings.

From the comments:

> I would like to compare the final output with the value of a variable
> and remove items from the listbox/stop adding items as soon as
> MaxSpeed equals the value of this variable. Thus in the animation you
> put up, assuming the value of this variable = 127, the final output
> would leave just the first row with a Maxweight = 80000.

You could change the output portion to the below:

```
Dim target As Integer = 127
lstOutput.Items.Clear()
lstOutput.Items.Add(header)
For Each row In results
    lstOutput.Items.Add(row.ToString)
    If row.MaxSpeed = target Then
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

Comment: There is a little problem though. The data I provided was just a subset of the full dataset I needed to re-organize. I figured once the principle was established for the sample, it would apply to the bulk as well. Your code worked for about 50% of the rows in the listbox and then started to give wrong output for the rest. I can't seem to figure out why by looking at the code. I'm going to modify the original question to include the full dataset so you can see for yourself.

Comment: You will find that the position of Time and T_Desc values have been swapped in this instance. I modified that in your code to give me output with the swapped columns. Anyway, I hope you can take a look at it.

Comment: My apologies for being unable to space out all the columns in the original dataset. They were just too many to do. I do hope you can identify each row and column output though. @Idle_Mind

Comment: If those two values have been swapped, then you'd change to `Time = Integer.Parse(values(5))`, and `T_Desc = Integer.Parse(values(2))`.  Everything else would stay the same.

Comment: But your wording worries me.  Has it been swapped for the ENTIRE set, or just certain parts?

Comment: yes I changed those two as you've specified and in the output, the entire set was swapped. It's just that for I think Max_Weight Values <= 60,000, the row is no longer selected by the maximum corresponding value of T_Desc.

Comment: Okay... so what would the new rule be for <= 60,000?

Comment: My bad. Your code was perfect. I was supposed to order the output by T_Final instead of T_Desc. Thank you so much. I appreciate it.

Comment: Again, thank you for helping me out with the first problem. I would like to crave your indulgence to help me with a second issue which has crept up. I would like to compare the final output with the value of a variable and remove items from the listbox/stop adding items as soon as MaxSpeed equals the value of this variable. Thus in the animation you put up, assuming the value of this variable = 127, the final output would leave just the first row with a Maxweight = 80000. I hope my question is clear. I tried messing with your code but couldn't figure it out.  @Idle_Mind

Comment: been a couple weeks. Hope you've been well. 
Well, yet again, I've run into a wall with something I'd like to do with my data. So in summary, I'd like to go through the rows and for each MaxWeight category, go through the Maxspeed values and print out the row with the highest T_final value, which at the same time maximizes MaxSpeed at that specific Maxweight. That in addition to imposing the variable constraint you included the other day. I have modified the original question to explain what I mean better. I hope you can help me. :)

Answer (score 0):

There's not enough info yet to provide a complete solution. We're still missing the type used for the objects in the ListBox, and to know exactly what you mean by "print them out". But I can still help some, by using a pretend type named `LineItem` with a Property matching each the fields shown in the sample (removing spaces for syntax compliance).

```vb
listBox1.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.MultiExtended
listBox1.SelectedItems.Clear()

Dim weightGroups = listBox1.Items.Cast(Of LineItem)().
               GroupBy(Function(i) i.MaxWeight, Function(i) i)
Dim MaxPerWeight = weightGroups.Select(Function(g) g.OrderBy(Function(i) -1*i.T_desc).First())
 
For Each item As LineItem in MaxPerWeight
    listBox1.SelectedItems.Add(item)
Next
```

Comment: The types of the objects used are as follows; 
Max_Weight, Double; Max Speed, Integer; Time; Integer, T_Emerg; Integer, T_final; Integer and T_Desc; Integer. 
I tried your code but I think it was triggering an error due to the unresolved type of "LineItem". @Joel Coehoorn

Comment: Yes. As I mentioned, that is a place holder. Replace that with the actual type of the items in the listbox. For the listbox to display, there must be one type with those items as properties. Perhaps DataRow, where you also need to check the properties by name or index. You may also need to add some Parse() or Convert() calls if all of your values are really strings.

Comment: Also, here's a .Net Fiddle with a C# version to prove the basic concept works: https://dotnetfiddle.net/0nsrjo Notice the hard work in `Test()` function is basically a one-liner.